# denormal flushing in floating point arithmetic, function approximation

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

Out of curiosity, what's the meaning of "denormal flushing" in the context of floating point arithmetic? Do you know a good reference for such topic?

I have some book but actually i can't find anything.

I need to understand how this definition is usually applied when a math library (i.e. function approximation) is going to be implemented, and how this definition somehow influence the ulp error of the function implemented compared to the "real" function.

Comment: That i need this explanation applied in function approximation, and some pseudocode as far as trivial this could be, it would be helpful.

Comment: Is it ok now? Sorry for before

Comment: The first thing you would want to clarify is whether ulp error can be computed in a meaningful way when the result is zero because flush-to-zero is in effect. I would claim that it is not.